# Fundamental group of group of homeomorphism of a compact surface

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, mapping-class-group

I'm reading "A Primer on Mapping Class Group", and there is something I don't understand in the proof of Theorem 4.6.

Define $\mathrm{Homeo}^+(S)$ to be the group of orientation-preserving homeomorphisms of $S$ and define $\mathrm{Homeo}_0(S)$ the connected component of the identity in $\mathrm{Homeo}^+(S)$. The group $\mathrm{Homeo}^+(S)$ is endowed with the compact-open topology.

**Theorem 1.14:** *Let $S$ be a compact surface, possibly minus a finite number of points from the interior. Assume that $S$ is not homeomorphic to
$S^2$ , $\mathbb{R}^2$, $D^2$ , $T^2$ , the closed annulus, the once punctured disk, or the once punctured plane. Then the space $\mathrm{Homeo}_0 (S)$ is contractible.*

**Theorem 4.6:** *Let $S$ be a surface with $\chi(S) < 0$, possibly with punctures and/or boundary. Let $(S,x)$ be the surface obtained from $S$ by marking a point $x$ in the interior of $S$. Then the following sequence is exact:$$1 \to \pi_1(S,x)\to \mathrm{Mod}(S,x) \to \mathrm{Mod}(S) \to 1.$$*

In the proof of Theorem 4.6, it is said : *By Theorem 1.14 the group $\pi_1 (\mathrm{Homeo}^+ (S))$ is trivial.*

I don't see how to deduce this fact from Theorem 1.14. Is it obvious that one can always find an homotopy from one homeomorphism to another?

Comment: The group $\pi_1 X$ is trivial if $X$ is contractible, almost by definition. (And $X$ is contractible iff every connected component of it is.)

Comment: @anomaly A contractible space is automatically connected

Comment: @Max: Yeah, basepoint stuff.

Answer (score 1):

By Theorem 1.14 $\text{Homeo}_0(S)$ is contractible, hence every connected component of $\text{Homeo}^+(S)$ is contractible (consider group structure of $\text{Homeo}^+(S)$). As each connected component is contractible the whole space must be simply connected.